# Tests using Webdriver with remote HTMLUnit having trouble logging into gmail

Tags: watir, htmlunit, webdriver

For some reason, after logging into a site like gmail, htmlunit is not working.  It is not able to find html elements.

The following is a very simple ruby script that shows the problem, note it assumes that webdriver server is running on the same machine running it:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'rspec/expectations'

##
## THE FOLLOWING TWO WAYS WORK
#
#browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :firefox)
#browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => :internet_explorer)

##
## THIS WAY FAILS
##
capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.htmlunit(:javascript_enabled => true)
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:remote, :url => "http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", :desired_capabilities => capabilities)

#Login to gmail
browser.goto "http://gmail.com"
browser.text_field(:id,'Email').set 'roberttestingstuff041'
browser.text_field(:id,'Passwd').set 'k4238chsj55983w'
browser.button(:id,'signIn').click

sleep 5.0  #sleep shouldnt be needed, but just to be sure we are waiting long enough for log in to complete

frame = browser.frame(:id,'canvas_frame')
#It fails on the next line when using htmlunit
frame.link(:text, 'Sign out').exist?.should == true
frame.link(:text, 'Sign out').visible?.should == true
frame.div(:id, 'guser').exist?.should == true
frame.div(:text,'Compose mail').exist?.should == true
```

Note that if I create the browser object using firefox or IE, this simple test works.

It seems to get hung up on the redirects that happen during the login process.  The site I am really trying to test follows a very similar pattern, so I set up this simplified example with gmail which seems to show the same problem.

Can anyone help turn this into a passing test?  Note that I can get a similar test to work using Celerity, which is also based on HTMLUnit, so I believe there should be some way to make this work?

This is the error that shows in the webdriver server, clearly showing it failing to find the attribute:

```
12:31:16.321 INFO - WebDriver remote server: INFO: Executing: [find element: By.xpath: .//a[normalize-space()='Sign out'
] at URL: /session/1297704604365/element)
12:31:17.996 WARN - WebDriver remote server: WARN:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate a node using .//a[normalize-space()='Sign out']
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_21'
Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
        at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByXPath(HtmlUnitDriver.java:699)
        at org.openqa.selenium.By$6.findElement(By.java:205)
        at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver$4.call(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1133)
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm thinking that Gmail is detecting our headless browser (in this case HtmlUnit with Rhino) does not support JavaScript.

If you look at the return from Gmail after

```
 browser.button(:id,'signIn').click
```

You will see that we are on a "JavaScript must be enabled" page

```
p browser.text
 "<style> #loading {display:none} </style> <font face=arial>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Gmail in standard view. However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. To use standard view, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, then <a href=\"\">try again</a>. <p>To use Gmail's basic HTML view, which does not require JavaScript, <a href=\"?ui=html&zy=c\">click here</a>.</p></font><p><font face=arial>If you want to view Gmail on a mobile phone or similar device <a href=\"?ui=mobile&zyp=c\">click here</a>.</font></p> \n Loading tim.koops@gmail.com\342\200\246 \n\n\n\n Loading standard view | Load basic HTML (for slow connections)"
```

In this case we could go to the HTML only version of Gmail to get you through, but unfortunately I think we're stuck for now. I will pass on this failing test case to the webdriver developers for review.

Also, hope those aren't your real Gmail credentials!

Comment: This first error on selenium server seems to support that theory `17:06:43.903 ERROR - runtimeError: message=[Automation server can't create object] sourceName=[script in https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&view=js&name=main,tlist&ver=kuSlkWliRXI.en.&am=!vqwfOGj_CUv7BT7CrnU2bm5B2G10ERe89KLW98l8P6s-zn6kKbKEL16Q&fri from (271, 18) to (287, 10)] line=[274] lineSource=[null] lineOffset=[0]`

Comment: Line 274 `if(H){if(H)try{var uta=new ActiveXObject("L2.NativeHelper");if(uta.gcTracer)...` Am wondering if the attempted instantiation of ActiveXObject is at play here?

Comment: Yup, you are correct.  Looking at the log from the webdriver server this is clear, it is able to log into gmail, but gmail throws out the "We've detected a slow Internet connection. To speed things up..." message.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable javascript for the HtmlUnit driver.
It's disabled by default. 
Use the Capability HTMLUNITWITHJS as opposed to the default HTMLUNIT.
I'm using the names in the Python bindings, but I'm sure Ruby is using something similar.